# Geofencing with locationmanager, execute code on didEnterRegion

Tags: swift

I have simple demo app for geofencing, the app is also working when closed/killed.
Now when the user has installed the app and kills it the geofencing is still working fine.
When user arrives in the set Region the delegate function "didEnterLocation" is doing 2 things. 1. make a local push notification that the user is in the Region 2. write to Userdefaults a simple string "entered location".

Iam a bit confused because i did not expect to be able to execute code (on didEnterLocation excepted the push notification) when the app is totally killed.

My question is: anybody have experience what the possibilities are on executing code ? Can i do a network request when the user enters the location ? and is this accepted bij apple ?

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        scheduleLocalNotification(alert: "didEnterRegion")
        print("did enter location")
        //save data to userdefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.set("write something over here", forKey: "location")

        //would it be possbile to do a network request over here ? and is this accepted bij apple
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app can run in Background.
It is legal to make a network call here.

It is like a Background fetch (in Background Mode).
The app is wakened by System that may have 30 seconds to do a small amount of work. But be careful with high CPU usage while the app is running in the Background.

- [Request Always Authorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization),
- [Setup Background Mode for Location Update](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background)
- [Background Fetch setup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app)

Comment: Did you find documentation on this?

Comment: @saro 
I updated my answer to add some ref URLs about Background Handling in iOS.

The common rule of background time budget for iOS app is ~ 30 secs.
After 30 secs, app will be suspended. I tried with both `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` & `BGAppRefreshTask`.

Comment: Yes but thats why iam confused, i know about the BGtasks, but i did not setup this in my example app. I cant find in the apple docs the confirmation that when didEnterRegion is hit there wil be a BGtask .

Comment: @saro 
I just give you an example that relates to background handling for iOS.
So you can try it to solve your task. It is legal to make an internet call here.

Whenever app can run in Background, System will allow it to run for a short duration, such as: 30 seconds. Because System needs to manage the Background time budget for each app to keep app runs in Background with reasonable frequency/interval, it is for power saving mostly.